# Is it possible to write to serial terminal program via JTAG interface?

Tags: serial, msp430, jtag

I have a CC430F5137 wireless development kit from Texas Instruments that I program via a JTAG interface, MSP-FET430UIF. On the computer side, the JTAG interface is connected to a USB port. Is it possible, for debugging purposes, to write to a serial terminal program via the JTAG interface?

Comment: I seem to remember using a `printf` on a TI C2000 and having it send the characters to a debug terminal in Code Composer via JTAG. Though this was years ago before Code Composer was based on Eclipse so I'm not sure if this is still true.

Comment: @embedded.kyle, after reading your comment I searched a little bit on using printf in Code Composer, and you are right. I should be able to use printf to display variables values to the console without having to introduce break points in the program. I havn't tried it yet, but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely yes, however it may be tricky.

If the micro does not have programmatic access to the jtag pins, you may have to use debugger functionality such as breakpoints and reading/writing volatile variables to accomplish mailboxing data interchange.

Ugly to implement, potentially problematic if you have realtime tasks, but the beauty is if you make it work it's all software so you can abstract the ugliness into a library on each end.